# Full bleed column with bottom padding with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I'm converting a HTML page with `wkhtmltopdf` from HTML to PDF. My page consists of a left column with full bleed background color. How can I force a bottom/top padding so that my content is not pushed against the edge of the page (as demonstrated below), while keeping the full bleed  background color for the left column?

I've tried `p {page-break-inside: avoid;}` without success. Setting padding on the page level goes against the full bleed.

[image]