# How to have text margin but full-bleed background using print stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf

I have an HTML page with a small fixed (i.e. non-scrolling) full-bleed (i.e. zero-margin) background around the edge.  I'm trying to set up the `@media print` stylesheet so that it prints well, and I'd like to keep the full-bleed background in the printed (PDF) version as well.

If I set `@page { margin: 0; }` then the background extends to the edge of the PDF exactly how I want, but page-broken text goes all the way to the top and bottom of the page without any margin.  If I set `@page { margin: 2cm; }` then I get reasonable margins on top and bottom of every page, but the PDF has an ugly blank white border that ruins the full-bleed background effect.  I've tried adding a `@page { background-image: url(...); }` but this doesn't seem to work at all in Chrome.

Is there some way to get the best of both worlds?  To keep both the full-bleed background image but also have reasonable top/bottom-margins on the page breaks?

I found a [somewhat-related question about wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778684/full-bleed-column-with-bottom-padding-with-wkhtmltopdf) but it was never answered.

Comment: My guess is that it's no possible to control where page breaks go when printing. Text might be zoomed in, they might choose to print landscape, or might choose a different size of paper.  Too many user-controlled variables that you can't factor for in CSS

Comment: Seems like you want `@page { margin: 2cm 0; }` ?

Comment: Note that the user can decide whether to print a background image or not. In Chrome look at the printers settings and make sure background images are allowed.

Comment: Please add enough code so we can see the problem. The solution may depend on exactly what your HTML structure is.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example